# That's how "I" looks like.

Tags: grammaticality

Is the sentence correct? I wanted to put "I" not as a subject - referring to me but as a noun - referring to the narrator which is me. So I was wondering if I can do this in a twisted way you know, pointing towards me but in an indirect way.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Check out [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which may be more appropriate for your question.  The sentence is wrong in any case, 'That's *what* I *look* like' is grammatical, not 'That's how I looks like'.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using "I" (including the inverted commas) as a third-person singular reference to yourself, use third-person singular verb agreement: *looks like*.

> In English grammar, *illeism* is the act of referring to oneself (often habitually) in the third person.
>
> Example: "I do mind, *the Dude* minds. This will not stand, you know. This aggression will not stand, man."
>
> [- thoughtco](https://www.thoughtco.com/illeism-self-talk-term-1691145)

In this example, the speaker refers to himself as "the Dude" in the third person. Note that agreement of "minds" is third-person singular.

While it's uncommon to refer to oneself in the third-person singular via the first-person singular term "I", your use of scare quotes *just* nudges it to acceptability.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you are referring to 'I' as in a singular noun being the orthographic letter or symbol where the third person form of the verb, 'looks', would be used, 'I' referring to the speaker is still the subject and thus the verb should be in the first person singular, 'look'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then the answer is no. But it is also worth noting that we cannot usually combine "how" and "looks like". There are two grammatical options:

- This is how John looks.
- This is what John looks like.